# How do I stop QuickTime from repeatedly stealing file associations?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, file-association, quicktime

Every time I update Quicktime on both Vista and XP, I lose file associations I made for VLC (my preferred player).  I only keep QT around for the odd browser video, and would prefer to keep it without it surprising me every couple months by stealing file associations.

Comment: This is what I hate the most about Quicktime also.

Comment: Agreed.  Also with regards to the answer about advanced setup, I've checked the appropriate checkbox every single time I install Quicktime and without fail it steals the associations it wants from.  So incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 4):

Buried in the advanced setup there is a checkbox to keep it from checking and reclaiming. Wish I could remember where though... I stopped using QuickTime a while back in an effort to simplify the media players that continually were sprouting on my PC... MediaPlayerClassic Home Cinema handles everything I need it to and then some.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, QuickTime has some stuff in its settings about file associations, or something that takes you to a tool to manage them.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest using [Quicktime Alternative](http://www.free-codecs.com/quicktime_alternative_download.htm) instead of the full blown Quicktime from Apple.  It has plugins for all the major browsers and allows you to play Quicktime files in any video player.  I have never had a problem with file associations using this software.

Comment: Does it allow you to watch HD trailers on apple.com?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it.